# Нужно ли подвязывать протоколы на weak ссылки?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Всем привет, недавно столкнулся с вопросом: нужно ли делать протоколы weak ссылками?

Если я использую класс - очевидно - да. Но когда я покрываю их протоколами - это невозможно. А нужно ли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Но когда я покрываю их протоколами - это невозможно

Это возможно. Для примера можете посмотреть `UITableView` там делегат/датасорс реализованы `weak` протоколами с типом `AnyObject`

Для примера:

```
protocol A: AnyObject {
    func aa()
}

class B: A {
    func aa() {
        print("aa")
    }
}

class C {
    weak var aType: A?

    init(aClass: A?) {
        aType = aClass
    }
}

let b = B()
let c = C(aClass: b)
c.aType?.aa() 
// aa
```

Comment: То есть для сервис-ориентированной архитектуры лучше свои сервисы (протоколы) наследовать от AnyObject?

Comment: Вы должны явно указать что протокол может реализовать только клас. можно еще заменить `AnyObject` на `class` -> `protocol A: class {}`

Answer (score 1):

Вовсе не обязательно везде использовать weak. Только если объекты ссылаются друг на друга (во избежания цикличных ссылок, где два объекта держат друг друга сильными ссылками). Почитайте побольше про ARC в iOS.

Вот два примера с сильной и слабой ссылкой в поле с протоколом.

```
// 1. Пример со слабой ссылкой

protocol ServiceOutput: AnyObject {
    func somethingDidHappen()
}

final class Service {

    // Держим слабой ссылкой инстанс ServiceOutput
    // weak требует чтобы протокол использовался только для классов, 
    // поэтому ServiceOutput наследуется от AnyObject (тот же эффект используя Protocol: class)
    weak var output: ServiceOutput?
}

// 2. Пример с сильной ссылкой (на примере dependency injection)

protocol AuthorizationServiceProtocol {
    func login(with name: String, password: String)
}

final class AuthorizationService: AuthorizationServiceProtocol {
    func login(with name: String, password: String) {
        // ...
    }
}

final class UserService {

    // Держим сильной ссылкой инстанс AuthorizationServiceProtocol
    private let authorizationService: AuthorizationServiceProtocol

    // Для работы UserService нужен сервис авторизации
    init(authorizationService: AuthorizationServiceProtocol) {
        self.authorizationService = authorizationService
    }
}
```